# Pandas strip string from column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file that looks as follow:

```
code.   timestamp.    message.     name.      Id.              action
1.        time.        message.    name.     some text - id    action
```

I would like to target the id column and strip everything starting from the space after the `-` until the beginning for the string if the column contains a `-`.
basically this is what I would like as an output.

```
code.   timestamp.    message.       name.        Id.              action
1.        <time.>     <message.>    <name.>       id               <action>
```

looking at some documentation I found this solution.

```
df['id'] = df['id'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('-').rstrip(' - '))
```

but this just strips everything from the left and the right of the `-` which is not the result I want.

can anyone help me to understand how can I target that space after the `-` and remove everything before it please?

Answer (score 1):

**Given:**

```
                        Col1
0             some text - id
1  remove this text - 012345
```

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd

mydf = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['some text - id', 'remove this text - 012345']})              

mydf['Col1'] = mydf['Col1'].str.extract(r'- (.*)')

print(mydf)
```

**Outputs:**

```
     Col1
0      id
1  012345
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first replace everything before `-` and then strip to remove extra spaces.

```py
df["id"].str.replace(r".*-", "").str.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split the strings on `-`  and then get the right part of the string, as follows:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].str.split(r'- ').str[-1]
```

If there can be more than one occurrence of `-`  in the string and you want to split only on the first occurrence, you can use:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].str.split(r'- ', n=1).str[-1]
```

**Demo**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['some text - id', 'another text - 2nd hypen - abc']})              

                               id
0                  some text - id
1  another text - 2nd hypen - abc

df['id'] = df['id'].str.split(r'- ').str[-1]

    id
0   id
1  abc
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['some text - id', 'another text - 2nd hypen - abc']})              

                               id
0                  some text - id
1  another text - 2nd hypen - abc

df['id'] = df['id'].str.split(r'- ', n=1).str[-1] 

                id
0               id
1  2nd hypen - abc
```